# server 2012r2: Cannot add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I am trying to run powershell script for backups on Server 2012 R2.
I Have installed Windows server Backup feature but when try to execute

```
Add-PsSnapin Windows.ServerBackup
```

I am getting error

```
 PS C:\Users\administrator> add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup
add-pssnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'windows.serverbackup' is not installed on this computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (windows.serverbackup:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

I have researched and everything is relating to Server 2008 where you install command-line tools alone with Windows Server BAckup. Server 2012 doesn't have it...
Any help appreciated

Comment: Well, the obvious question now becomes... is the Windows Server backup plugin installed?  Check with `get-pssnapin`.  And if it's not showing up as installed, [try to install it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732081.aspx), and see what happens.

Comment: This is the whole thing... it is not installed / registered. When installing Windows backup feature option for command line is not there. your link is pointing to Server 2008

Comment: Oh, I think I see.  Try running `Get-Command –Module WindowsServerBackup`.  The Windows Server Backup cmdlets are built-in to PowerShell 4, so they no longer need to be installed, as they did in Server 2008 R2.  If the backup feature is installed, you'll get a list of valid cmdlets you can run.  If not, you'll get nothing.

Comment: Thanks a million, I get a list of commands. and can run them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `Get-Command –Module WindowsServerBackup`. The Windows Server Backup cmdlets are built-in with PowerShell 4, so they no longer need to be installed, as they did in Server 2008 R2 and PowerShell verison 3.

If the backup feature is installed, you'll get a list of valid cmdlets you can run, and you're good to go. If not, you'll get nothing, and you need to install (or re-install) the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Your source problem is that Command-line Tools feature for Windows Server Backup is not installed.

Go to Add Features, Windows Server Backup Features. Do check and install Command-line Tools, and when done re-issue "add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup". You will see no error, just a prompt in a new line.